# Its possible to send logs from two different machines without logstash to elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elk

I have installed on a ubuntu machine elasticsearch, kibana and auditbeat so im monitoring the log events on the ubuntu machine. I also installed winglogbeat on a windows machine to monitorize it too and I configured it to send the logs to the elasticsearch on the ubuntu machine.
This is the configuration of the winglogbeat.yml

[image]

But when I tried to run the winglogbeat I get the following error when its trying to connect to kibana on the ubuntu machine.
[image]

On the ubuntu machine kibana, elasticsearch and auditbeat works properly.
This is the configuration of the elasticsearch.yml:
[image]

And this is the kibana.yml configuration:
[image]

Comment: please don't post pictures of text, logs or code. They are difficult to read, impossible to search and replicate (if it's code), and some people may not be even able to see them :)

Comment: @Nat is Kibana running on the same machine as ElasticSearch? Have you created credentials for Kibana and are those the same as ElasticSearch ?

Comment: @karanshah Kibana is running on the same machine as elasticsearch, i dont have created credentials on kibana and elasticsearch but it works properly without credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I just modify the file kibana.yml to allow connections from a remote host:
Server.host: "0.0.0.0"

Comment: Awesome I assume its all sorted now. To your original question though, yes it is possible to send logs from multiple machines to elasticsearch without using logstash. You can use any beats agent and directly send the output to elasticsearch.